# Scroll synchronously with slideDown

Tags: jquery

The slideDown applied to a div does the slideDown but doesn't scroll the page down and the div slided down div remains hidden from view. Is there a way to scroll the page down synchronously with slideDown so this div will be visible entirely?

```
$('#log').append('<div id="in_log">...</div>');
$('#in_log').slideDown('fast');
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

slideDown does not scroll the page automatically down. Also, you cannot scroll the page synchronously with the slideDown as you cannot determine the final height of the division. What you can do is to scroll the page using .animate() after the slideDown animation is completed

Comment: Well, is there even any way to do so as I want by the using jQuery?

Comment: Yes, let the division scrollDown, and AFTER it finishes, scroll down the page using .animate()

Comment: Why not? If '#in_log' has a fixed height + some defined margin/padding (put it on the element instead of css to use it dynamically) you could calculate the to-be height. After that it's just 2 parallel calls.

Answer (score 0):

you could scroll to the top of the div by doing:

```
var top = $('#in_log').offset().top
$(window).scrollTop(top);
```

Comment: yes, but in your solution at-first we slideDown this div and only AFTER this we can start scrolling. But I want that these two processes occur at the same time :-)

Comment: @cockroach-eater `slideDown` doesn't change the offset().top.. the height will become larger, but the top is still the same.